# Does metal toggle switch in simple AC lamp circuit need to be grounded

Tags: ac, circuit-design, safety

I am getting into woodworking and would like to build a simple lamp like the one in this video on Youtube: https://youtu.be/BY5FzfxvZrg In the video, the lamp body/enclosure is built out of wood.  The switch used to turn the lamp on and off is a basic metal toggle switch mounted through the top of the wood enclosure.  I noticed in the comments that some have expressed concern that the switch is not grounded.  Is this lamp unsafe as-is, or should I ground the switch?  If it needs to be grounded, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A company, Leviton, made (possibly now discontinued) [metal bat toggle switches for double insulated applications](https://www.fruitridgetools.com/electrical/appliance-switches/toggle/leviton-metal-bat-toggle-switch-8a-125v-4a-250v-spst-on-off-for-double-insulated-applications-738/).  The metal mounting plate is not exposed on the back of the switch and I suppose the metal bat is 'double insulated' from the contacts.  They seem to be available on eBay, Amazon and elsewhere.

I cannot say if these are up to the latest modern standards but they are marketed for the specific application.  For the little extra they might cost it could be a bit of extra peace of mind.

The obvious alternative is to get a [plastic shell switch with a plastic bat](http://www.terapeak.com/worth/leviton-plastic-bat-toggle-switch-8a-on-off-double-insulated-applications-1738/231643896373/) and it is automatically double insulated.

Designing in a fuse is probably overkill, risk averse manufacturers do not do it and it is one more point of failure (connections) and user stupidity faults (incorrect fuse) and provides very little extra protection.  Mostly because the live and neutral polarity cannot always be trusted even with an earthed or polarised mains plug the polarity is only as good as your last electrician.

As per the comment above the strain relief DID include a cable tie but no protection from rotation, the goop covered the back of the Edison base terminals.  Adding an additional section of good (woven glass reinforced) sleeving over the wire where it enters the cabinet that was then bent and fixed in place with a small durable strain relief would be good insurance.

Fine stranded wire is ill suited for screw terminals but with a ring lug they can be fine under a screw, with a bootlace ferrule they are fine in a cavity terminal and screw terminals that have a pressure plate.  The switches above come with wire tails that reduce the number of termination points by one at least and allow the use of a wire nut or in line crimped splice for one other which are safer than a badly made termination under a screw head.

I applaud the novel way the YouTube clip maker re-purposed the para-cord outer sock as a vintage decorative silk/cotton wire covering.

Comment: Any wiring is only as good as the last electrician. Which is why electricians always do a polarity test on all outlets before handing over the job.

Comment: @IanBland Do they really, on all outlets?  I mean why even have a routine for testing if everything is always correct?  OP may not have control of his outlets but can do the best with his lamp.

Comment: The whole point of testing is error correction. Every endeavour has an error rate, and thus whenever something matters (for safety, for instance), you should have a testing and correction phase. Or, you can stick your fingers in your ears and operate the switch with a broomhandle, etc.

Comment: I switched this to the accepted answer.  Those Leviton plugs will save me a bunch of time and headache.  Thank you @KalleMP

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe that such exposed metal should be grounded since it could become energized by a single fault condition where the metal housing inside touches, say, a loose wire.

You can use a piece of metal between the switch and the inside of the wood to ground the metal parts, and connect that to the ground on a 3-wire line cord. Or use a switch without exposed metal.

More metal inside would also slightly reduce the fire risk. I also suggest a fuse.

Comment: A loose wire is a real possibility with that setup - there seems to be very little in the way of strain relief on the wire as it enters the housing. Even something as simple as a chunky cable tie around the wire would help. It looks like he's just stuck it in with latex or silicone or something. Hell, even tying a knot in the wire would be an improvement...!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where would I put the fuse in the circuit?

Comment: In the "hot" (ugh, I hate that name. It's LIVE! Water's hot!) wire between the incoming wire and the switch. Ideally a panel mount fuse socket (one of the screw in ones) so you can easily change the fuse if you ever need to.

Comment: Yes, as @Majenko says in the hot wire. You can use an inline fuse if you don't want to mount it through the wood.

Comment: Watching speeded up video is annoying, heh. Yes, any exposed metal should be earthed ("grounded"), and the cable should have a strain relief. A fused plug would be sufficient circuit protection.